# jQuery DatePicker date format with current calture

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using [DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) with date range and I want to use the current calture format.
I know how to get the current calture:

```
var calture = '<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name %>';
```

But this does not give me the date format that I need to for the date picker DateFormat.
How do I get the current calture date format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var cultureLanguageTag = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag;
var defaultCulture =  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(cultureLanguageTag);
```

This gives the default dateformat.